# Cannot perform option-mapped operation with type: (Boolean, _57) => R

Tags: slick

I have next filter

```
type DatabaseID = Long   

val filter = moderators.filter(m =>
          (m.created < before) &&
          (m.userType inSet userTypeList) &&
          (if(true) m.mcID === mcIDFilter else true)
        )
```

where `m.mcID` has `Rep[Option[models.DatabaseID]]` type and `mcIDFilter` `Option[models.DatabaseID]`.

Why i'm getting next error?

```
Cannot perform option-mapped operation
      with type: (Boolean, _57) => R
  for base type: (Boolean, Boolean) => Boolean
```

`_57`? What is it?

I have replaced condition with `true` for simplicity. If i remove line with condition or replace `m.mcID === mcIDFilter` with just `true`, code compiles fine.

Also if i remove `if` statement, it compiles without error:

```
val filter = moderators.filter(m =>
      (m.created < before) &&
      (m.userType inSet userTypeList) &&
      m.mcID === mcIDFilter
    )
```

I found that this error appears when type one of operands have not the same type.

I also tried

```
val filter = moderators.filter(m =>
      (m.created < before) &&
      (m.userType inSet userTypeList) &&
      (if(true) m.mcID === mcIDFilter else true:Rep[Boolean])
    )
```

but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found how compile this. It's ugly, but work.

```
val filter = moderators.filter(m =>
      (m.created < before) &&
      (m.userType inSet userTypeList) &&
      (if(true) m.mcID === mcIDFilter else Some(true):Rep[Option[Boolean]])
    )
```