# Cannot perform option-mapped operation Play Scala Slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am trying to run below query

```
val query = for {
  ((a, b), c) <- join.filter(
    x => arrays.map(p => x._1._1.status inSetBind p).getOrElse(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true))

  )
} yield ((a, b), c)

sync(db.run(query.result))
```

arrays is of type Option[Array[String]]

> Cannot perform option-mapped operation [error]       with type:
>   (Option[Boolean], _87) => R [error]   for base type: (Boolean,
>   Boolean) => Boolean [error]           && arrays.map(p =>
>   x._1._1.status inSetBind
>   p).getOrElse(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true)) [error]

^

What seems to be the cause of error?

Comment: Could it help you? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290575/cannot-perform-option-mapped-operation-with-type-boolean-57-r

Comment: @AndriyKuba No it didn't. I have already went through matching questions but none helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue to be with slick. I just needed to add another parenthesis around the inSetBind block and it worked.